# Convert resultant Integer to Float with five decimals in a math operation

Tags: python

I have to calculate the percentage of the song being played in the player

For Example when:

```
    CurrentTime = 11 (Int)
    TotalTime = 222 (Int)
```

I need the percentage played and I do this by following

```
    PlayedBufferPercent = (CurrentTime*100)/TotalTime
```

-> Manual calculation results in 4.95495495495 which is as expected.
Now I want to round this to 5 decimal values = 4.95496, I tried the below using python but did not result in proper output.

```
    PlayedBufferPercent = float((CurrentTime*100)/TotalTime)
    PlayedBufferPercent1 = ("{0:.5f}" .format(PlayedBufferPercent))
```

Result = 4.00000 but I want 4.95496, Please help

Comment: Add `from __future__ import division` to the beginning of file. It makes every `/` between integers a float division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing the arithmetic using integer operations. This expression:

```
(CurrentTime*100)/TotalTime
```

is evaluated using integer arithmetic because the operands are all integers. And so it evaluates to `4` and then when you convert to float with

```
PlayedBufferPercent = float((CurrentTime*100)/TotalTime)
```

you merely convert `4` into `4.0`.

You need to perform the arithmetic using floating point operations. You can force that by making at least one of the operands be a float. For example:

```
PlayedBufferPercent = (CurrentTime*100.0)/TotalTime
```

Alternatively you could make `CurrentTime` and `TotalTime` be floats.

Finally, you are not going to get `4.95496` mind you. Rather the answer is `4.95495` which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `PlayedBufferPercent` variable is still an int - which is expected given that it's the result of division of 2 ints.

```
PlayedBufferPercent = (CurrentTime*100)/TotalTime
4
```

even once you add the cast to float, it's too late and you've already lost the precision.

Easiest way to fix this would be to make the `CurrentTime` and `TotalTime` into floats either by explicitely `float(TotalTime)` or implicitely `TotalTime = 11.0` (same with `CurrentTime`)

Comment: No, `PlayedBufferPercent` is a `float`. It's converted from an `int` to a `float`.

Comment: not true the way he wrote it, I;ve edited my answer as I can;t get the formating to work in a comment

Comment: No. Look below where it says: `PlayedBufferPercent = float((CurrentTime*100)/TotalTime)`

Comment: To be fair, the question did offer two competing variants of the assignment!